# Where to put SQL scripts generated by a Maven build?

Tags: java, maven, ant, nexus

We're in the process of replacing Ant builds by Maven builds. At the moment, we have a project that generates SQL scripts in the Ant build and puts them into our directory structure for artifacts.

Now with introducing Maven, we will replace that directory structure by a Nexus repository. I am not sure what to do with the generated SQL scripts.

Should I zip them and put them as (side) artifact into the repository?

Or should they be checked into version control?

Or is there another, more elegant way?

This probably applies to other automatically generated scripts, data, etc. as well.

Comment: If the scripts should be part or your project, just include the folder in the build dir, so when you package your app it's include.

Comment: The mentioned project (meaning its Ant script) just creates an SQL file and puts it into a directory. you would suggest to put this SQL file into a jar and put it into Nexus?

Comment: So, the scripts are not link to a version of your project ? If you want the script to be archived in nexus, either include it in your project (if pertinent), or create a new project/module (i.e new artifact id) so it can be managed by nexus.

Answer (score 2):

If your project needs to read these SQL files, then they can be generated in the `src/main/resources` folder. This will include them in the package (jar, war, ear, etc) to be deployed to Nexus.

By other hand, maybe it would be better to distribute the code that generate the scripts, not the scripts themselves.

This link may help you to understand Maven directory structure:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

I thing this can be helpfull for you.

Question: [What's the recommended location for SQL (DDL) scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686334/whats-the-recommended-location-for-sql-ddl-scripts)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686334/whats-the-recommended-location-for-sql-ddl-scripts